# ArcPy - How to Save to a txt file to reference and itterate

Tags: arcpy

What I would like to do with the following code snippet:

1. Check to see if a text file contains feature class names
2. If it does not contain feature class names, then write the feature class names to it
3. If the file which contains the feature class names does not equal the list in the feature class then check the feature class for projection, output a new projection if the new feature class is not projected properly, then append the text file to include the updated list of feature classes

The following is my code without errors but it is also not writing, nor is it returning the proper debugging checks I would expect.

```
import os
import arcpy
import traceback

CheckProjections = r"C:\Users\FC_CheckProjections.txt"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Distances.gdb"
outWorkspace = r"C:\Users\Distances.gdb"

try:

    # Check feature classes in --
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        # Check to see if txt document is empty
        with open(CheckProjections, 'w') as output:

            # If txt document is empty then fill with feature classes
            if CheckProjections == "" :
                output.write(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses())

                # If txt document does not equal the feature class list (meaning something new was added) then
            elif CheckProjections != arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() :

                # Use ListFeatureClasses to generate a list of inputs
                for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

                    # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
                    dsc = arcpy.Describe(fc)

                    # Define the spatial class to check against
                    if dsc.spatialReference.Name != 'NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_III_FIPS_0403_Feet':

                        # Determine the new output feature class path and name
                        outfc = os.path.join(outWorkspace, fc + "_NAD1983")

                        # Set output coordinate system
                        outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 StatePlane California III FIPS 0403 (US Feet)')

                        # run project tool
                        arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, outCS)

                        # append new projection list to txt file
                        output.write(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses())

                        # check messages
                        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
            else :

                print("no updates")

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    msg = arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    arcpy.AddError(msg)
    print(msg)

except Exception as ex:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)

    print(pymsg)
    print(msgs)
    print(ex.args[0])
```

This was my output:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\python.exe C:/Users/Desktop/code.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure that I understand your goal, but it I do so this example should work. I think you are "over" iterating, plus you are opening the file in each iteration and over writing the file. Check my proposition it may guide you, if it does not solve your problem let me know.

```
import os
import arcpy
import traceback

checkProjections = r"C:\Users\FC_CheckProjections.txt"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Distances.gdb"
outWorkspace = r"C:\Users\Distances.gdb"

try:
    # -- get feature classes
    lfc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    # -- read file
    file_lfc = None
    with open(checkProjections) as f:
        file_lfc = f.read().split(',')
    # -- process
    # If txt document does not equal the feature class list (meaning something new was added) then
    if set(file_lfc) != set(lfc):
        # Use ListFeatureClasses to generate a list of inputs
        for fc in lfc:
            # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
            dsc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
            # Define the spatial class to check against
            if dsc.spatialReference.Name != 'NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_III_FIPS_0403_Feet':
                # Determine the new output feature class path and name
                outfc = os.path.join(outWorkspace, fc + "_NAD1983")
                # Set output coordinate system
                outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 StatePlane California III FIPS 0403 (US Feet)')
                # run project tool
                arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, outCS)
                # check messages
                print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    else :
        print("no updates")
    # -- write the file with new info
    lfc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    with open(checkProjections, 'w') as f:
        f.write(','.join(lfc))

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    msg = arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    arcpy.AddError(msg)
    print(msg)

except Exception as ex:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)

    print(pymsg)
    print(msgs)
    print(ex.args[0])
```

Comment: What I got was the following error (which I will try and fix myself after work): PYTHON ERRORS:
Traceback info:
  File "C:/Users/Py.py", line 15, in <module>
    file_lfc = data.split(',')

Error Info:
'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer, forgot to read the file before splitting. Just to make it clear, you have to somehow encode and decode the list returned by `ListFeatureClasses`. For this, I choose to separate the values of the list by `,`, you can pick any other format.

Comment: I got the error as follows: Error Info: name 'data' is not defined -- for line 15 "if data and data != ','.join(lfc)." Should data be replaced with lfc ? Was this supposed to be for data and data != ",".join(lfc) ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update that part, let me update again. That part just try to compare both list. Give me a second to update.

Comment: Ok, so I use `set` to compare both lists (the one the file one `file_lfc` and 
the query one `lfc`). This comparison check that both have same elements, order does not matter. If order matters, the just compare the lists `file_lfc != lfc`

Comment: I'll try this change in a second--however--in testing I changed data to "if lfc and file_lfc != ','.join(lfc):" which seems to work though I am not sure how well---I also noticed that the section "else: print("no updates")" wasn't working. Is this because the "#--Write the file with new info" comes after the "no updates" else: section? Thank you so much for all the help. I'm only just starting to learn Python!

Comment: The comparison `file_lfc != ','.join(lfc)` is between list and string so will always be false. The `print('no updates')` occur when the comparison fail, you are right in the sense that if `file_lfc` is empty it should not print, in that way you can change the `else` for `elif len(file_lfc) == 0` or similar. The update of the file always occurs, you can change that also, although I thought it is not big deal in this case.

Comment: Glad it helps you!